JJ Thomsons experiment using oscilloscope
would it be possible to make a JJ Thomsons experiment using old oscilloscope with CRT. I have an old ussr oscilloscope C1-112A. I was thinking of making a Helmholtz coils around oscilloscope and by changing voltage measure deflection on oscilloscope.

The CRT oscilloscopes are based on the fact that electric fields deflect electrons. Not sure what the Helmholtz coils are supposed to do…

@Jon_Custer The B-field can be adjusted to return the beam which had been deflected by the E-field back to its trajectory with no fields present. It is the principle behind a velocity selector.

All done for you and there are a number of other experimental guides on the Internet.

A Wien filter is going above and beyond Thompson’s original deflection experiments.
